# Adding Show and Hide button to BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-design-library

I have this code;

```
<android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationItemView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_time"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="#E0E0E0"
        android:dividerHeight="4px" />

</android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationItemView>
```

I want to add a bar with a "Show" and "Hide" button to this ItemView. When i click show it will show ListView, when hide it will hide this ListView. Can i do it?

Comment: If your asking if that is possible, the answer is, Yes you can do it.

Comment: How can i do it? I never seen an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The show and hide functionality is already given on the answers, so I will add the example for *"bar with a Show and Hide button"*

```
<android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationItemView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:background="#123123">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_show"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Show" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_hide"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Hide" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_time"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="#E0E0E0"
        android:dividerHeight="4px" />

</android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationItemView>
```

Then apply the onclick functions of the buttons using the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these methods to show and hide

```
    v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or if you want to hide and use the place for other layout components you can use:

```
v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```